# casting generic-type list of maps

Tags: java, generics, bukkit

I'm trying to use spigot's [`ConfigurationSection#getMapList`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/configuration/ConfigurationSection.html#getMapList-java.lang.String-) which is of the type `<java.util.List<java.util.Map<?,?>>>`.

I know that in this specific case the values it returns will be of the type
`List<Map<String, List<Integer>>>`.

So I've written this:

```
List<Map<String, List<Integer>>> configSpawnpoints = this.getConfig().getMapList("key");
```

but get the error:

```
incompatible types: java.util.List<java.util.Map<?,?>> cannot be converted to
java.util.List<java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>>>
```

How can I cast my `List<Map<?,?>>` to a `List<Map<String, List<Integer>>>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wildcard return here implies that the API can't *guarantee* that it knows what types are going to be contained in the map.  Additionally, you can't force it to cast at compile-time since there's no concrete guarantee.  Your best hope is to cast this manually to a `Map` when you want to access it and deal with the error(s) at runtime.

```
List<Map<?, ?>> configSpawnpoints = this.getConfig().getMapList("key");
// to use it
Map<Integer, List<String>> mapPoint = (Map) configSpawnpoints.get(0);
```

Comment: Why did even trying a cast to `List<Map<Object, Object>>` fail? I thought everything in java was an `Object`

Comment: 1)  You can't cast to generic types.  It's not valid syntax.  2)  Type erasure means that you'd only ever get the raw types *anyway*, so `List<Map<Object, Object>>` would decay to `List`.  3)  A wildcard is not the same as an `Object` in generic terms.  `?` is for all intents and purposes an `Object`, but the wildcard itself implies that you do not know (or care) what reified type it actually is.